# Firestore transactions node.js inquiry

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

So I have been building a server in node.js and I am incorporating firestore. Currently I am using a transaction to update some data, but have noticed that the transaction will complete before the data has actually updated. I want the transaction to return after the data has completed updating. What exactly am I doing wrong here?

```
const userRef = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid)
const otherUserRef = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid2)
    try {
         const res = await db.runTransaction(async t => {
            const userDoc = await t.get(userRef);
            const otherDoc = await t.get(otherUserRef);
            
            t.set(userRef, {nickname: "mynickname"}, {merge: true});
            t.set(otherUserRef, {nickname: "myothernickname"}, {merge: true});
         }
     });
        // transaction success
     } catch (e) {
        // transaction error
     }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a `return` at the end of the transaction?

Comment: yes, somehow the same result.